# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'

Tags: python

Alguien puede ayudarme?
La última fila del código me da error.

```
os.chdir("./envolventes")


diractual = os.getcwd()

ficheros = os.listdir(diractual)


lista_sin_D = [ x for x in ficheros if "D" not in x ]

import re

lista_A_menor45 = [ x for x in ficheros if int(re.match('.*?([0-9]+)$', 
x).group(1)) < 45 ]
```

Comment: Tienes una cadena en la lista que no coincide con la expresión regular, lo que ocasiona que `re.math` retorne `None` en vez de un objeto `_sre.SRE_Match`, por lo que no puedes aplicar el método `group` sobre `None` .

Comment: Y como se solucionaría? Porque en la consola escriboint(re.match('.*?([0-9]+)$', "T1A50") y sí me devuelve 50

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Como los archivos tienen extension .txt debes cambiar la expresion regular por `.*?([0-9]+).txt` quedando asi:

```
lista_A_menor45 = [ x for x in ficheros if int(re.match('.*?([0-9]+).txt', x).group(1)) < 45 ]
```

Para expresiones regulares recomiendo mucho la siguiente pagina para evaluarlas y testearlas: [regex101](https://regex101.com/)

Comment: Perfecto!! Ahora sí. Muchas gracias a todos!!

Comment: Buenas, puedes valorar las respuestas como se indica [este enlace](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 1):

Tienes algún fichero que no se ajusta al patrón que le das.

Antes de extraer el grupo, debes chequear si `.match()` retorna  `None`. Para que puedas aplicarlo en una compresión de listas puedes hacer así:

```
def check(x):
    m = re.match('.*?([0-9]+)$', x)
    return False if m is None else int(m.group(1)) < 45

[ x for x in ficheros if check(x) ]
```

Para saber qué ficheros no pasan, basta invertir el filtro:

```
[ x for x in ficheros if not check(x) ]
```

Comment: No sé por qué pero no hace absolutamente nada

Comment: Te aconsejo que complementes tu pregunta con un conjunto de pruebas que podamos comprobar.

Comment: import os

os.chdir("./envolventes")


diractual = os.getcwd()

ficheros = os.listdir(diractual)
 
lista_sin_D = [ x for x in ficheros if "D" not in x ]

import re

lista_A_menor45 = [ x for x in ficheros if int(re.match('.*?([0-9]+)$', x).group(1)) < 45 ]




Ese es el código.

Y la lista ficheros está llena de ficheros con extensión .txt

Comment: Precisamente, necesitamos esa lista de ficheros para probar tu código y ver dónde falla. Pero ya te adelanto que tu expresión regular no tiene en cuenta la extensión `.txt` de los ficheros.

Comment: ficheros=[T1A1, T1A2, T1A3, ....T1A59, T1A60,
                T2A1, T2A2, T2A3, ....T2A59, T2A60,
                .
                .
                 T10A1, T10A2, T10A3, ... T10A59, T10A60,

Suponemos que los elementos que contienen D (T1D1, T1D2....) ya han sido extraídos

Comment: ¿Entonces tienen o no tienen extensión `.txt` los nombres de ficheros? Si pruebo con `T1A1` o cualquier otro nombre de la lista, no me da ningún error.

Comment: Si tienen... Perdón... sería 
 
ficheros=[T1A1.txt, T1A2.txt, T1A3.txt, ....T1A59.txt, T1A60.txt, T2A1.txt, T2A2.txt, T2A3.txt, ....T2A59.txt, T2A60.txt, . . T10A1.txt, T10A2.txt, T10A3.txt, ... T10A59.txt, T10A60.txt